# Incorrect language in url will lead me to "This webpage has a redirect loop" Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

My actual URL is  http://aghs/

Whenever I call the above URL, it will resolve to the correct page.

But if called with a page that does not exist, like  `http://aghs/invalidpage`, it will redirect to page not found page correctly.

But if I go to an invalid page name with only 2 characters, it goes into a redirect loop.

For example, whenever I am navigate to the URL with "sd" instead of "en" or "fr" like  `http://aghs/sd`, the sire returns:

> "This webpage has a redirect loop"

What I found is that whenever the site is called with an incorrect langauge, e.g.

```
var myFields = new SitecoreContext().GetCurrentItem<SEOFields>();
```

it returns a null value. But when calling with correct language `myFields` value is the correct value.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with `.htaccess' to me; please post your .htaccess.

Comment: Can you check if the current language is valid then if so get the seo fields otherwise default to en to get the seo fields?

Comment: You may have to create a custom Language Resolver processor overriding the default one to check or not check the URL string to serve your needs.